# How can I sort by a name on one table but return only a unique primary key?

Tags: mysql, union

How can I query one table just for sort order, but only get unique id's in order from another table?

I only wan't the unique book id form this query if possible. this is a one to many relationship, so there are many authors to one book, and thus the reason why I wen't with UNION ALL.

here's the query I came up with, but I keep getting `Unknown column 'a.author_name' in 'field list'`

```
SELECT b.id FROM books AS b
UNION ALL
SELECT a.book_id, FROM authors AS a
ORDER BY a.author_name DESC;
```

any help with this would be greatly apreceated

Comment: should probably remove the comma after `a.book_id` as well. AND, no need for the `authors AS a`, should be just `authors a`....

Comment: sorry typo on my part. it was in the query, I was messing with the query when asking the question.. my question, however still remains valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way if you need a **unique** book ID and yet you want to sort it based on the author's name (you say "there are many authors per book") is to use a `SUBSELECT` with `GROUP BY`.

In this case:

```
SELECT b.id
FROM books AS b
JOIN (
  SELECT book_id, MAX(author_name) AS author_name
  FROM authors GROUP BY book_id ) AS a
ON (b.id = a.book_id)
ORDER BY a.author_name DESC;
```

You can see a SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b3ec1/4/0).

Note that `MAX(author_name)` is necessary if you sort in descending order. If you wanted to sort in ascending order, you'd need to use `MIN()`.

```
CREATE TABLE books ( id integer, title varchar(32) );
CREATE TABLE authors ( book_id integer, author_name varchar(32) );

INSERT INTO books VALUES ( 1, 'The Book' );
INSERT INTO books VALUES ( 2, 'Book II');

INSERT INTO authors VALUES ( 1, 'First Author' );
INSERT INTO authors VALUES ( 2, 'Second Author' );
INSERT INTO authors VALUES ( 2, 'Third Author');
INSERT INTO authors VALUES ( 2, 'Another Author');
```

This yields first book II, since "Third Author" comes first in alphabetic descending order, then "The Book", for a total of two IDs.

If we were to add an author coming later than T to book 1,

```
INSERT INTO authors VALUES ( 1, 'Zaftig' );
```

...then the same query would return first book ID 1, then book ID 2.

Just adding a `DISTINCT` to the straight `INNER JOIN` might **not** work since it could reorder the `id`'s (you can see this in the fiddle by adding an author with name starting with Z):

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id FROM books AS b 
    INNER JOIN authors AS a ON a.book_id=b.id
    ORDER BY a.author_name DESC;
```

Comment: thank you very much for this answer... I only noticed today that the other answer can cause duplicates, which is defiantly what I don't want. this was very helpful... I also really like the site, SQL Fiddle, that you used.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using UNION then the columns specified in ORDER BY clause must be present in SELECT clause. Based on your requirement, you can get ONLY id with join

```
SELECT b.id FROM books AS b 
inner join authors AS a ON a.book_id=b.bid
ORDER BY a.author_name DESC;
```

Comment: Doesn't this return duplicate IDs as well, if there is more than one author per book?

Comment: @lserni I did not realize that until now... but you are totally right... it does.